# Setting color for an item of a view list in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to change the items color on the list view.

I tried that , but its not working:

android:textColor = "#FFFFFF"

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewToDo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

</ListView>
```

Comment: To change the items text color you need to go to the item resource and change it there or in code whenever the items getView() is called

Comment: The items are made dynamically ( from user's input ) - its a ToDo list app.
How do I get into the item attributes? and why isnt the color changed through setting the textColor inside ListView tag?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To create a listView you'll need one xml file to represent a row, right?
So, if you want the same color for all of the rows, you could just set `android:textColor="#FFFFFF"` there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To change listView items color, you should implement a custom adapter and pass it a view.
We can change the view attributes programmatically from the getView() methods which returns a View object.